Exclusion AMPscript not working in a journey
I'm using the AMPscript below in a Journey email. I have 2 DEs - one for the send and one for the exclusion. However, when I run the journey it still sends the email to the emails in the exclusion DE. Any ideas? Thanks!
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Exclusion_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME","EMAIL_ADDR_FIELD_NAME",EMAILADDR))>0


Jane, How are you populating the 3rd parameter of the LookUpRows() function? I would recommend to use emailaddr or AttributeValue('EmailAddress Column Name') to match with your exclusion Dataextension email address column.
